# How to read parameter from rb file in erb file

Tags: ruby, erb, rhomobile

I'm using rhoMobile platform
I'm trying to get a parameter in my erb file from rb file.
I have a properties file, in my app.rb file i'm getting values from keys in this properties file.
This value is saved in application.rb, and i want to use this value in my app.erb.
Here is some code:

```
myFunc(<%= Rho::RhoConfig.getValue %>)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myFunc('<%= Rho.get_app.getValue('key')%>')

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to question if your doing things right, but this should work:

```
myFunc("<%= Rho::RhoConfig.getValue %>")
```

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  var rho_config_value = <%= Rho::RhoConfig.getValue || 'null' %>;
  myFunc(rho_config_value)
</script>
```

Comment: you just did?  :) Although i found myself multiple times in this situation, @screenmutt feel free to offer another answer.

Comment: @Zippie it doesn't work, the rest is fine because it works whit hard coded text

Comment: It's OK to question when there is code-smell. Too often people ask XY questions, trying to solve a problem that has them painted into a corner, when they should back up and do it a better way. This is one of those times. A view shouldn't be computing values or hitting the RhoMobile code; That should have occurred prior to the view having control.